# Blocks editor not opening for App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I am running windows 7 on 64bit platform, every time i try to open Blocks Editor the AppInventorForAndroidCodeblocks.JNLP downloads, once i try to open the file, Its asking me how i should  open the file

[image]

Comment: are you using Google Chrome? did you install the App Inventor software, you can find it here http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/setup-mit-app-inventor.html

Comment: all i needed to do was update the version of java i had and the issue was resolved.